# iOS take screenshot programmatically

Tags: ios, screenshot

what is the most efficient way to take screenshoot in iOS7. I have try few methods but on iPad it take some about 1-1.5 sec to take screenshoot and I need to take it immediatly. Is there any method to do screenshot in split second?

Comment: Take a look at [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994709/screen-shot-not-provide-image-of-whole-screen), May it can Help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may this will help -

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)


    {
        size = CGSizeMake(320,500);
    }
    else{

        size = CGSizeMake(320,416);
    }


    CGRect screenrect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor]set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenrect);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *image1=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Comment: Well renderInContext is rly slow method :(

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1817/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014134):

> Starting from iOS 7, the UIView class provides a method
>   -drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates

Use `-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates` or `-snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` methods then.